# How can I get first letter of each word in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have multiple Names & I want to get first letter or each word. How can I do this?

My Code:-

```js
$('.testimonial-box').each(function(){
    let clientNameFirstLetter = $(this).find('.client-name').text();
    let clientNameSecondLetter = $(this).find('.client-name').text();
    let clientNameBothLetters = clientNameFirstLetter.charAt(0) + clientNameSecondLetter.charAt(0);
    $(this).find('.img-circle').text(clientNameBothLetters);
  });
```

```css
.testimonial-sectiioin{ display:flex; gap:45px;}
.testimonial-sectiioin .testimonial-box .img-circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 55px;
  font-family: proximaNovaBold;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="testimonial-sectiioin">
<div class="testimonial-box">
<div class="img-circle"></div>
 <p class="client-name">Rohit Verma</p>
</div>

<div class="testimonial-box">
<div class="img-circle"></div>
 <p class="client-name">Vipin Kumar Verma</p>
</div>

<div class="testimonial-box">
<div class="img-circle"></div>
 <p class="client-name">Neha Aggarwal</p>
</div>
</section>
```

ThankYou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split` to split the text based on the space. So you will get your first name and second name.

So you can take the first letters of both words. Easy.

If you have more than 2 words in the name, you can use a map/forEach to get each letter's.

```js
$('.testimonial-box').each(function(){
    let clientName = $(this).find('.client-name').text();
    let clientNameBothLetters = clientName.split(" ")[0][0]
 + clientName.split(" ")[clientName.split(" ").length - 1][0];
    $(this).find('.img-circle').text(clientNameBothLetters);
  });
```

```css
.testimonial-sectiioin{ display:flex; gap:45px;}
.testimonial-sectiioin .testimonial-box .img-circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 55px;
  font-family: proximaNovaBold;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="testimonial-sectiioin">
<div class="testimonial-box">
<div class="img-circle"></div>
 <p class="client-name">Rohit Verma</p>
</div>

<div class="testimonial-box">
<div class="img-circle"></div>
 <p class="client-name">Vipin Kumar Verma</p>
</div>

<div class="testimonial-box">
<div class="img-circle"></div>
 <p class="client-name">Neha Aggarwal</p>
</div>
</section>
```

**EDIT**

As per the request, the snippet updated in a way that only two letters will be shown in the `img-circle`. So for "Vipin Kumar Verma", it will be "VV".

Comment: I need to display just two letters instead of three or more than two

Comment: So what would you wanna print for "Vipin Kumar Verma"? "VV" ?

Comment: @RohitVerma, updated the answer snippet to accommodate only 2 letters from each words (First word, and last word)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.testimonial-box').each(function(){
    // Get client name
    let clientName = $(this).find('.client-name').text();
    
    // Create an array with words inside the name
    let splittedName = clientName.split(' ');
    
    // Now let's loop all words and save the first letter
    var name = ''
    splittedName.forEach(n => {
      name += n[0]
    })
    
    // Set name to current image circle
    $(this).find('.img-circle').text(name);

  });
```

```css
.testimonial-sectiioin{ display:flex; gap:45px;}
.testimonial-sectiioin .testimonial-box .img-circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 55px;
  font-family: proximaNovaBold;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="testimonial-sectiioin">
<div class="testimonial-box">
<div class="img-circle"></div>
 <p class="client-name">Rohit Verma</p>
</div>

<div class="testimonial-box">
<div class="img-circle"></div>
 <p class="client-name">Vipin Kumar Verma</p>
</div>

<div class="testimonial-box">
<div class="img-circle"></div>
 <p class="client-name">Neha Aggarwal</p>
</div>
</section>
```